# Nearest numbers in the list

Tags: list-manipulation, code-review

I am just curious that there is any better way to write the code to search the nearest value than what I wrote below

```
peaks={{127, 1}, {133, 0.992}, {139, 1}, {1762, 0.984}};

DeleteDuplicates[
Table[
  Select[peaks,
   (peaks[[i, 2]] - 0.1 <= #[[2]] <= peaks[[i, 2]] + 0.1) &&
     (peaks[[i, 1]] - 20 <= #[[1]] <= peaks[[i, 1]] + 20)
    &]
  , {i, 1, Length[peaks]}]]

(*Output*)
{{{127, 1}, {133, 0.992}, {139, 1}}, {{1762, 0.984}}}
```

I think there will be much simpler and easier way to write in mathematica... Any help?

---

**Edit**

I try to gather the value by the near position

[image]

You can see that three points are All in blue point, and one point is at yellow dot. I just want to find this cluster

Comment: [`Nearest`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Nearest.html). But please describe what you want the code to do.

Comment: A slight tweak to your code: `Gather[peaks, 
 And[Abs[#1[[1]] - #2[[1]]] < 20, Abs[#1[[2]] - #2[[2]]] < 0.1] &]`, assuming I understand your question. But I echo @corey979: Can you explain what it is you're trying to do?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, I add the edit below

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
peaks={{127, 1}, {133, 0.992}, {139, 1}, {1762, 0.984}};
```

1. `FindClusters[peaks, Method -> "Agglomerate"]`

   > {{{127, 1}, {133, 0.992}, {139, 1}}, {{1762, 0.984}}}
2. `cc = ClusterClassify[peaks, Method -> "DBSCAN"]; GatherBy[peaks, cc]`

   > {{{127, 1}, {133, 0.992}, {139, 1}}, {{1762, 0.984}}}

Answer (score 3):

This should be exactly reproducing the OP code, using `Nearest` :

```
 Sort /@ (Nearest[peaks, #, {Infinity, 1.},
      DistanceFunction -> (Max[Abs[Subtract@##/{20, .1}]] &)
           ] & /@ peaks) // DeleteDuplicates
```

and you might also consider `DistanceFunction -> (Norm[Subtract@##/{20, .1}] &)`

Comment: `DistanceFunction -> EuclideanDistance`?

Comment: @yode you could also use `EuclideanDistance` but you still need to apply the scale `{20,.1}` , so like `EuclideanDistance[#1/{20, .1}, #2/{20, .1}] &`

Comment: @george2079 I think this code was what I asked on question, but sorry that I did not accept your post.